# using gdb backtrace to debug MPI code

Tags: c++, gdb, mpi, backtrace

Using gdb with backtrace gives following output,

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x2aaaaffd3700 (LWP 32109)]
[Thread 0x2aaaaffd3700 (LWP 32109) exited]
Detaching after fork from child process 32110.
Detaching after fork from child process 32111.
Detaching after fork from child process 32112.
Detaching after fork from child process 32113.
Detaching after fork from child process 32114.
Detaching after fork from child process 32115.
Detaching after fork from child process 32116.
Detaching after fork from child process 32117.
Detaching after fork from child process 32118.
Detaching after fork from child process 32119.
Detaching after fork from child process 32120.
Detaching after fork from child process 32121.
Detaching after fork from child process 32122.
Detaching after fork from child process 32123.
Detaching after fork from child process 32124.
Detaching after fork from child process 32125.
Detaching after fork from child process 32126.
Detaching after fork from child process 32127.
Detaching after fork from child process 32128.
Detaching after fork from child process 32129.
Detaching after fork from child process 32130.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install     fftw-3.2.1-3.1.el6.x86_64 glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64 nss-pam-ldapd-0.7.5-14.el6_2.1.x86_64
Detaching after fork from child process 32131.
Detaching after fork from child process 32133.
Detaching after fork from child process 32134.
Detaching after fork from child process 32135.
Detaching after fork from child process 32136.
Detaching after fork from child process 32137.
Detaching after fork from child process 32138.
Detaching after fork from child process 32139.
Detaching after fork from child process 32140.
Detaching after fork from child process 32141.
Detaching after fork from child process 32142.
Detaching after fork from child process 32143.
Detaching after fork from child process 32144.
```

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.

```
0x00000000004a3104 in phase::Mobility::Average ()
#0  0x00000000004a3104 in phase::Mobility::Average ()
#1  0x00000000004a3523 in phase::Mobility::Average(phase::Field&, phase::BoundaryConditions&) ()
#2  0x000000000046fcda in phase::Diffusion::CalculateMobility(phase::Field&, phase::Composition&, phase::BoundaryConditions&, phase::Mobility&) ()
#3  0x0000000000441a3e in MyParallelism<MyParallelBlock>::Run() ()
#4  0x00000000004436dc in main ()
```

What does order of the output functions indicate? should I be looking for the last function of the output?
How can I further narrow down the line which has caused arithmetic exception?

**EDIT**
Running with -g option gives,

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00000000004a5fa4 in phase::Mobility::Average ()
#0  0x00000000004a5fa4 in phase::Mobility::Average ()
#1  0x00000000004a63c3 in phase::Mobility::Average(phase::Field&, phase::BoundaryConditions&) ()
#2  0x0000000000472fea in phase::Diffusion::Mobility(phase::Field&, phase::Composition&, phase::BoundaryConditions&, phase::Mobility&) ()
#3  0x000000000042686e in MyParallelBlock::DoTimestep (this=0x7c9368)
    at Parallelism.cpp:100
#4  0x00000000004450d9 in MyParallelism<MyParallelBlock>::Run (
    this=0x7fffffffd2f0) at Parallelism.cpp:164
#5  0x0000000000446ad3 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcd8)
    at Parallelism.cpp:242
```

but cause of arithmetic exception is not narrowed down. this added the information that exception is in the run loop (which was already known). I was expecting some more information within function  `phase::Mobility::Average ()`. What is significance of the numbers `0x0000000000446ad3, 0x00000000004450d9` etc? can i get some information out of these numbers?

Comment: Your question has not much to do with MPI. Recompile with `-g` in order to instruct the compiler to emit debug information and then you'll also see the source file name and the line of code where the error occurred. You should be looking at the function at the top of the stack, namely `phase::Mobility::Average()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev, thanks for the tip. Can you please have a look at the output with -g enabled?

Comment: According to your new stack trace, you compiled `Parallelism.cpp` with `-g`. However, in order to get the file and line where the arithmetic exception occured, you'll also have to compile the `phase::Mobility` class/namespace with `-g`. You currently have file+line information for `#3`, `#4`, `#5`. But you need this for `#0`.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for pointing out that, with that I could figure out where the problem is. If you can post the comment as answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gdb` stack trace shows the functions in the order they lie on the call-stack from top to bottom (whereas the stack grows from bottom to top).

If gdb catches an *Arithmetic Exception* or *Segmentation fault*, the function which incurred the error will be shown at position `#0` in gdb's stack trace.

In order to get the file and line information of where the error occurred, recompile your program with debug symbols. Use the compilers `-g` flag to do so. Make sure to recompile at least those files in which the failing function (see `#0` on the stack trace) is declared and implemented.

In your case, you'll have to recompile the file which implements the class/namespace `phase::Mobility` with the `-g` option.